# How do I check my promotional credit with Amazon?

Tags: amazon

I'm trying to figure out how much promotional credit I have before I make a purchase (stupid 1-click for digital purchases).

I do not want to check my gift card balance. I want to know how much promotional credit I have.

For example: As of writing this question, Amazon gives $1 MP3 credit with the purchase of any CD album. I've purchased a few of those, but I don't know how many MP3 credits I have. Where can I check that?

I know I've seen a page in the past with it on it, but I can't find that page now.

Comment: it's kind of crazy how ridiculously hard it is to find this page unless you already know where to look.

Comment: I want to know this as well. My circumstance is the same as in the original post.
The answer above does not take me to the place where I can see my CREDIT BALANCE.
(This should not be difficult. So why am I - are we - having such a hard time with this simple thing?)

Comment: As of June, 2015: http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html/?docId=1000811661#gc

Comment: As well as 'music and video', you can also get promotional credit in other departments. (In particular as a quid pro quo if you choose 'no rush delivery' rather than 'one day delivery' from Amazon Prime.)

Comment: If I were a cynic, I'd suspect Amazon deliberately obscure your promotional credit so you forget to use it. I've certainly forgotten about mine before and lost it (the expiry date can be as short as two months).

Comment: Worse than that: on 15th August I received promotional credit that expired 1st September--only 17 days to spend it. Previous orders I made in June and July gave me credit to expire October. The way Amazon choose the expiry date seems unpredictable and unfair.

Comment: @ColonelPanic Unpredictable sure, but it's their promotions, they can do whatever they want?

Comment: @McKay Respect for the consumer demands the terms of the promotion be made clear before you take it up. In the case above, I complained about the unexpectedly short expiry date, and Amazon refunded me cash.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/norushcredits via December 2016 comment in [thread](https://www.amazon.com/forum/kindle/ref=cm_cd_et_md_pl?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=Fx1D7SY3BVSESG&cdMsgID=MxCXXPRI2OQJ2U&cdMsgNo=106&cdPage=5&cdSort=oldest&cdThread=Tx2VQOP31Z8WLGJ#MxCXXPRI2OQJ2U)

Comment: @qyb2zm302 I don't have enough reputation to post this as an answer, but you should!

Answer (score 81):

1. Log in to your Amazon account
2. Click the [Credit Redeem page](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?ie=UTF8&docId=1000296831).
3. Click the **"Enter Your Code"** button. It will bring up a dialog with *almost* all your credit balances.
4. Visit [this NoRushCredits link](https://www.amazon.com/norushcredits) to see your Your No-Rush Reward Balances **and when they expire**. (Includes Digital Rewards and 
   Prime Now Rewards)

The Amazon UK site has an [equivalent page](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/feature.html?ie=UTF8&docId=1000706783) with a "Check your balance" button.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting:  I have never seen any credit appear in the "Kindle Editions" box, but I have definitely had these credits apply to kindle books.  Unfortunately there is no way to know that they will be applied until *after* you purchase the kindle book (because you can only buy them with one-click).

Comment: Is there any UI element on Amazon.com that will take you to the Credit Redeem page, or must you use a link such as the one above?

Comment: I made a blog post (ad-free) about this process to make it easier to understand: http://calebbron.com/stuff/amzn-no-rush-promo-credits.html

Comment: As of September 2016, the 'check your balance' button has been removed. Sleazy Amazon.

Comment: I just bought a kindle book now.  I had $4 of credits in the "Kindle Editions" box.  No credits were put towards my purchase.  I say the "promotional credits" are B.S. until I see otherwise.

Comment: It seems that this doesn't work for new types of credit like Prime Now. Now you need to go to https://www.amazon.com/norushcredits

Comment: The UK page does not have a "Check your balance" feature (anymore). The only way you can see if you have promotional balance is if you try to check out an order. Note that it will only show you one credit at a time.

Comment: Carl's comment wasn't visible, so I missed it.  I added it to the answer.

Comment: Also, all the fine print on the Prime Now Rewards (which I think I summarized quite concisely) makes them close to worthless, _n'est pas_?

Comment: This stopped working as of May 2019. I'd been using it for years.

Answer (score 22):

You can tweak the other answer's link to get directly at the promotional credit.  (You must be signed into your Amazon.com account first.)

Just append to the link https://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html/?ie=UTF8&docId=1000296831

```
&gcIsProcess=0
```

This will cause the Credit Balances to instantiate without any clicking. 
Additionally, to automatically scroll down to this popup, append

```
#gc
```

**Direct link** (no clicky, must be signed in) https://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html/?ie=UTF8&docId=1000296831&gcIsProcess=0#gc

Lists individual credit balances:

- Amazon Gift Card
- Amazon MP3
- Amazon Instant Video
- Kindle Editions
- Software/Video Games

Answer (score 15):

If you're looking for a more stable link, I recommend you use:

- http://www.amazon.com/mp3redeem

Amazon publicizes this URL in emails as follows:

> For redemption instructions and additional information, click here http://www.amazon.com/mp3redeem.

Since its publicized, and it looks like a marketing URL, I'm guessing Amazon will ensure this link always points to the most recent version of the Credit Redemption page.

Comment: If you're an Amazon Smile user, that links also works if you change "www." to "smile."

Comment: An update: they now seem to be promoting this version of the URL: https://www.amazon.com/norushcredits

Answer (score 12):

Reposting something stated in the comments:

Use https://www.amazon.com/norushcredits

Comment: `norushcredits` is better than the `mp3redeem` page because it shows the expiration date.

Comment: As of 1/24/2022, `norushcredits` is the only answer I found to be useful.

Comment: `norushcredits` is useful for those credits, but there are other kinds of credits too that don't show up there.

Answer (score 9):

I'm curios why [Lam Chau's](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/6974/lam-chau) helpful answer in the comments to the OP is not listed as an answer:

[amzn.to/mp3-balance](https://amzn.to/mp3-balance)

> easy to remember short link: [amzn.to/mp3-balance](https://amzn.to/mp3-balance) :) – [Lam Chau](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/6974/lam-chau) Oct 6
>   '12 at 3:10

It's been working for years and is basically a short link to what [adam](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/45957/adam) and [Senseful](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/207/senseful) answered above (showing breakdown of credits into categories including Amazon Gift Card, Amazon MP3, Prime Video, etc.). All three resolve to slightly different URLs (note the different docId in each), but all three seem to work fine.

Nevertheless, [Senseful's](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/207/senseful) "canonical" link (http://www.amazon.com/mp3redeem) seems like the best bet for a bookmark if you don't mind the extra click on the "Check your balance" button.

Comment: I get "Sorry we couldn't find that page" at [amzn.to/mp3-balance](https://amzn.to/mp3-balance).  Perhaps it's since been removed.

Comment: @M.Justin Looks like you're correct. It was working for several years.